# Prestashop 1.7.6.1: problem 3 digits after the decimal point

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

I tried to add 3 decimal places to the price level in Prestashop 1.7.6.1, the value is well configured in the back office. but the system only displays 2 digits .

PS: I dont have this problem with other versions

[image]